# Выделить число с любыми разделителями "," "." RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пользователь вводит число, для своего удобства он может разделять тысячи ',' при этом записывая дробное число. То есть:
1000 ||
1,999 ||
19,999.4353.
Выделить это число надо из текста, так что надо регулярное выражение которое выдаст это число.

```
let num = value.math(/RegExp/g);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, возможно:

`/\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?/g`

```
> '1000 1,999 19,999.4353'.match(/\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?/g)
[ '1000', '1,999', '19,999.4353' ]
```

Comment: Возможно, я недопонимаю задачу. Если вам не нужно сохранение групп, скобки можно сделать незапоминающими, я изменил шаблон. Что касается полноты числа, может, приведёте примеры? Числа из вашего вопроса вроде находятся полностью.

Comment: Черт, где то я затупил) Сенкс)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, но оно не идеальное. Если кого то натолкнет на мысль лучше, кидайте в комменты)

```
/([\,?\.?\d+]+)/g
```

В этой регулярке есть проблема. Отрабатывают значения "," и "." так же отрабатывают их множественные повторения. Происходит это из за '[ ]'. Фиксится 2 способами:

1. Заменить их на '( )', однако это добавит вторую сохраняемую группу в ваш массив. Если вам это не критично, можно использовать этот метод.
2. Поставить проверку на "," и ".". Моя проверка выглядит так:

   `if (!/\,+/.test(val) || !/\.+/.test(val)){}`

Comment: Вам точно нужна регулярка на JS? Ваша не выглядит как JS, там ? внутри [] используется как литерал '?'.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант

```
 const regex = /[-+]?(?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?/gm;
```